# What would be a basis for the free vector space $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have been reading about free vector space, but I would like to see it on a concrete example. The definition I have is the following:

> Let $X$ be a set. Define $C(X)=\{f:X\to \mathbb{F} \mid f^{-1}(\mathbb{F}-\{0\}) \text{ is finite} \}$. One can show that $C(X)$ is a vector space with underlying field $\mathbb{F}$.

In addition,

> $C(X)$ also has a basis. Let $y \in X$. If we define $$\delta_y(x)=\begin{cases} 1,&\text{ if }x = y,
> \\0,&\text{ if } x \ne y.\end{cases}$$
>   Then it is easy to see that for any $f\in C(X)$, we have
>   $$ f = \sum_{y\in X} f(y) \delta_y$$

These all make sense to me, except that I don't see what they look like!

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$. What does $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ look like? First, the dimension (or cardinality of basis) is uncountable. This is already quite terrifying. Second, I cannot even come up with a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that it has finite support. Can anyone help me write out a vector in $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Also, is $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ isomorphic to (as vector spaces) any more familiar vector space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think about $\mathbb{R}^2=X$ in $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ as having any of the structure one typically attributes to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  From the point of view of the free vector space, this is just a set with no additional important information except for its cardinality.

Pick some arbitrary points $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n \in X$, and some arbitrary elements $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then the function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ which sends $x_i$ to $\lambda_i$, and any other point $x$ to $0$, has finite support.

In fact, all the elements in $C(X)$ look like this.

As you've noted, a basis is given by $\{\delta_x \mid x\in X\}$.  Let's just identify $x$ with $\delta_x$.  Then a function $f$ above can be written as $\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n$.  This looks innocent enough.

The idea behind a free vector space is that we want to create a vector space which has $X$ (or at least something naturally associated with it) as a basis.  So we expect such a vector space to be the set of elements of the form above.

The construction given is simply making this rigorous.

Comment: Does there exists any continuous function in $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: Only one, the zero function.  Otherwise, if $f(x)>0$, then there is an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $f$ is positive on that neighborhood.  Since all non-empty open sets are (uncountably) infinite, it follows that $f$ does not have finite support.  Likewise with $f(x)<0$.

Comment: I see. It seems like $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ does not have many nice functions then :( I also saw the notes saying that free vector space is usually huge. In this example, I suppose that it's because even the basis for $C(\mathbb{R}^2$ is already uncountable?

Comment: On the contrary, $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has many nice functions.  They're just finite linear combinations of the $\delta_x$'s.  Do they have anything to do with the structures of $\mathbb{R}^2$? No, but that's the point.  And yes, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is uncountable, so $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$, at least compared to a finite dimensional space, is giant in that sense.  (however, its cardinality is the same as $\mathbb{R}$, so it is only 'giant' in the sense of dimension)