# What is $\bigoplus_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

[One way to define free vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014271/what-would-be-a-basis-for-the-free-vector-space-c-mathbbr2) is to consider a set of functions. To be more concrete, if we let our field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, and our set be $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$, then the element in the free vector space $C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2)$ would be functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in form

$$f = \sum_{y\in \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2} f(y)\delta_y$$

Yet, according to [this notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf), we can also formulate free vector space using direct sum.

$$C_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2) := \bigoplus_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$$

I am having some trouble understanding the second notation since $\delta_{(m,n)}$ is a function. How do we take direct sum here? Are we taking direct sum of vector spaces? Does the following make sense (ignoring the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is in fact uncountable)

$$\bigoplus_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}=\mathbb{R}\delta_{(v_1,w_1)} \oplus \mathbb{R}\delta_{(v_2,w_2)}\oplus\cdots$$

But what is the thing on the right hand side? Why is it equivalent to the first definition of free vector space?

Comment: What do you mean by "free vector space"? Vector spaces are always freely generated by any basis in the usual sense of these terms in universal algebra.

Comment: @RobArthan Let $X$ be a set. Define $C(X)=\{f:X\to \mathbb{F} \mid f^{-1}(\mathbb{F}-\{0\}) \text{ is finite} \}$. One can show that $C(X)$ is a vector space with underlying field $\mathbb{F}$ We say $C(X)$ is a free vector space generated by $X$.

Comment: Do we? References?

Comment: @RobArthan Please see http://planetmath.org/freevectorspaceoveraset

Comment: OK. But I find that to be really unhelpful terminology and I think it has not helped you. If $X$ is any set, there is a vector space $\Bbb{F}\langle X\rangle$ with $X$ as a basis. In your example, the function $f(x, y)$ needs to be *finitely supported*, i.e., you need $f(x, y)=0$ for all but finitely many pairs $(x, y)$.

Comment: @RobArthan Umm that definition _is_ confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\delta_{(m,n)}$ is considered as an element of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2}$ of *all* functions $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ (with addition and scalar multiplication defined pointwise).  So $\mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2}$, consisting of all scalar-multiples of $\delta_{(m,n)}$.

Now, your description of $C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2)$ is also a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2}$, and it contains $\mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$ for all $(m,n)$.  What is being asserted here is that in fact $C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the internal direct sum of the subspaces $\mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$.  That means that each element $f\in C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be written uniquely as a sum $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i$, where each $f_i$ is a nonzero element of a different $\mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$.  But indeed, this exactly what your description of $C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2)$ gives: any $f$ can be written as $\sum_y f(y)\delta_y$, where $y$ ranges over all points such that $f(y)\neq 0$, and $f(y)\delta_y$ is some nonzero element of $\mathbb{R}\delta_y$.  The uniqueness of this representation is just the fact that the vectors $\delta_{(m,n)}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I understand that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2}$ is a vector space of functions, and $\mathbb{R}\delta_{(m,n)}$ is a subspace for a given $(m,n)\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$. But for a given function $f$ (say $f(\vec{v},\vec{w}) = \vec{v}^T \vec{w}$), if I want to write it as linear combinations of $\delta$'s, how should I do it?

Comment: You can't do this for _any_ function, you can only do it for functions that are $0$ at all but finitely many points, which is exactly what $C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2)$ is.  For such a function, $f=\sum_{(m,n)}f(m,n)\delta_{(m,n)}$, where $(m,n)$ ranges over all points such that $f(m,n)\neq 0$.